# $lookup and $unwind gives no result when nested array is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following post collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5ddb15e540442a7d4213c"),
    "content" : "content1",
    "comments" : [ObjectId("5af2a10dc56ad8378a3fbffa")]
}
```

I have following comments collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af2a10dc56ad8378a3fbffa"),
    "likeBy" : [ObjectId("5ac8ba3582c2345af70d4658")],
    "post" : ObjectId("5ad5ddb15e540442a7d4213c"),
    "comment" : "comment1",
}
```

I made following `$lookup` query... Query works perfect when comments array has `ids` like

`"comments" : [ObjectId("5af2a10dc56ad8378a3fbffa")]`

... But when comments are emptied like

```
    "comments" : []
```

then it return empty array... Atleast it should return the first `match` condition `{ $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }}`...

```
const post = await Post.aggregate([
          { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }},
          { $lookup: {
              from: 'comments',
              localField: 'comments',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'comments'
            }
          },
          { $unwind: '$comments' },
          { $addFields: {
            "comments.isLiked": {
              $in: [ 
                mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id), 
                "$comments.likeBy"
              ]
            }
          }}
          { $group: {
              _id: '$_id',
              content: {$first: '$content'},
              comments: {$push: '$comments'}
            }
          }
        ])
```

So my expected result should be

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5ddb15e540442a7d4213c"),
        "content" : "222222222222222222222222222222222222222222",
        "comments" : []
    }
```

Comment: [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) - What does it say on the page about empty arrays?

Comment: `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` I have used it but does not work

Comment: @NeilLunn  And also if I use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` then it gives error inside `$addFields` `likeBy` requires array

Comment: @NeilLunn hi... Am I missing something here... Or it cannot be possible... Or mongodb competency and limits ends up here...

Comment: What you are missing is providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The problem is "of course" with the `$unwind` statements where the `$lookup` produces an empty array due to no foreign match. But is actually up to you to provide "reproducible" information within your question and an "expected result" which can actually be obtained from the "data you provide". The documents you have added do not reproduce the result, nor is there any expected result which can be obtained from "the documents you provide".

Comment: Also  focusing on "minimal" here, as we don't need to see your whole collection. Just enough so that the same "missing" result can be replicated on your current code. Then someone can tell you how to correct. But not presently. Hence "no answers".

Comment: @NeilLunn I have updated the question... Please have a look

Comment: Your very own words - *"But when comments are emptied like.."* So where is the example? Read back as this is what you have been repeatedly asked to do and yet you still have not done this. And of course now the pipeline being used bears no resemblance to the initial pipeline with multiple `$lookup` and `$unwind` statements. If the result of `$lookup` is "empty" and you want to keep the parent document then you **"must"** use the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`, or at least "properly explain" what you expect as a result and ALL source data so we can suggest if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @NeilLunn now I got it man... `$lookup` and `$unwind` does fail when the nested array is empty... It does not return even the root element where data is present... Now I will go with the pipeline...

Answer (score 2):

only **preserveNullAndEmptyArrays** to **true** default its false.

```
{
      $unwind: {
        path: '$toUserData',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
```

Please refer link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: If I use it then it gives me error in next line `addFields`... `error: $in requires array`